# Insights: Do admins get counted in the insights

Tags: analysis, facebook-insights

Does Facebook count a page administrators impressions/visits/etc for their page? i have created a page and was wondering if my views on my page were being counted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are being counted the same as any other user.